# Running Jmeter Without UI

Tags: performance, load, jmeter

I am running jmeter without UI MODE. Here is my script:

nohup ./jmeter.sh -n -t /home/gdev/jmeter/apache-jmeter-23/project.jmx -l /home/gdev/jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.13/ResultsTest.jtl

Error in NonGUIDriver com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : input contained no data

Answer (score 0):

Look into jmeter.log file and show its content so that we have more details on error.